# Set theoretical definition of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm writing a project about what a function is. The goal is to reflect on the many definitions, representations. Be it a graphical representation of an equation, or an abstract intangible example. The goal is to consider examples of functions through the various definitions and see where the edges are, or where they might begin to fail. An example could be how its not possible to explicitly define the unit circle, but it can be done implicitly using the implicit function theorem.

So my question is really about looking for holes in the set theoretical definition other than 'if the requirements of being a function are not met then its not a function'. Hence my now (hopefully) clarified question

Is there an example of an equation/relation/graph where the set theoretical definition of a function has some problems being satisfied but another definition would succeed e.g we could find an implicit function using the implicit function theorem or some such other technique?

Comment: What do you mean by the definition 'won't hold'?

Comment: Not clear... The set-theoretic one is the definition of the mathematical object : *function*.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can write down your definition of a "function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you are after, but a class function acting on a proper class is not a function in the set-theoretical sense, because its domain is not a set.

An example of such a class function is the power set function, which maps each set to its power set.

A class function is given by a logical formula $\phi(x,y)$ on sets such that $\phi(x,y)\land\phi(x,z)\implies y=z$. Here $\phi(x,y)$ describes the condition "the class function applied to $x$ gives $y$".

For example, the power set function mentioned above would be described by $\phi(x,y)\equiv\mathcal P(x)=y$. Or using only basic formulas, $\phi(x,y)\equiv\forall z(z\in y\iff\forall w(w\in z\implies w\in x))$

---

Another example where at least the definition in ZFC doesn't work, is the combinator calculus. Combinators are functions acting on functions and returning other functions. The simplest combinator is the identity function, which just gives its argument back.

So why does this not work with the usual definition of functions in the context of ZFC? Simply because such a combinator can be applied to *itself.* For example, the identity combinator applied to itself gives itself again.

But the usual set-theoretical definition of functions involves a set of pairs of possible function arguments and function returns (the so-called graph of the function). So a function that can be applied to itself would have to contain a pair that in turn contains the function itself. But this would violate the axiom of regularity.

Note that you *can* describe combinators within ZFC set theory, it's just that you cannot define the combinators themselves as set-theoretic functions. Instead, you can simply define an application function that takes two combinator functions, and gives back the result of applying one of them to the other. Since that application function is not one of the functions you can pass to the combinators, this is unproblematic.

Comment: Nice. This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If a "function" does not satisfy the set-theoretic definition of a function, then, by definition, it is not a function

Comment: Can you write it as comment?